# Getting coherent response with Mule ESB's LDAP connector on search

Tags: java, xml, ldap, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to use the LDAP connector for Mule ESB. I am able to see some results but I am unable to do anything with it as the response isn't in any format.

What I'd like to do is take the response and convert it to some sort of CSV but that's not the main question.

My main question is I don't know how to process my response there isn't a lot of information online about this.

Here's a part of my response it's confidential information so I cannot show much but you'll get the idea.

> ��srjava.util.ArrayListx����a�Isizexp  w sr"org.mule.module.ldap.api.LDAPEntry���5���L
>   attributest.Lorg/mule/module/ldap/api/LDAPEntryAttributes;LdntLjava/lang/String;xpsr,org.mule.module.ldap.api.LDAPEntryAttributesf�&/f�L
>   attributestLjava/util/Map;xpsrjava.util.HashMap���`�F
>   loadFactorI thresholdxp?@wt
>   streetaddresssr6org.mule.module.ldap.api.LDAPSingleValueEntryAttribute"�k.�eLvaluetLjava/lang/Object;xr+org.mule.module.ldap.api.LDAPEntryAttribute�C�ؠJ�Lnameq~xpt
>   streetAddresst85, street iashdapsd
>   postalcodesq~t
>   postalCodetpostal codetmailsq~q~tuser.user@org.orgttitlesq~q~tthetitletphysicaldeliveryofficenamesq~tphysicalDeliveryOfficeNametPLACEtsnsq~q~ tNamet
>   departmentsq~q~#tServicet givennamesq~t  givenNametSurnametlsq~q~*tCitytstsq~q~-tSTATEttelephonenumbersq~ttelephoneNumbert9789 987 987xtACN=Surnam Name,OU=myou,OU=myou,OU=myou,DC=mydc

Here's my flow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:wmq="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ldap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap/current/mule-ldap.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq/current/mule-wmq-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd">
    <ldap:config name="ldapConf" url="ldap://host.host.host:389/" authDn="user@host.host" authPassword="secret" doc:name="LDAP"/>
    <flow name="activedirectoryGetUsers">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP (Deprecated)" path="activeDirectory"/>
        <ldap:search config-ref="ldapConf" doc:name="LDAP" baseDn="OU=myOu,DC=myDC, DC=myDC" filter="(&amp;(objectClass=user)(Company=*mycompany))" scope="SUB_TREE">
        <ldap:attributes>
                <ldap:attribute>dn</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>GivenName</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>sn</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>mail</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>telephonenumber</ldap:attribute>    
                <ldap:attribute>Department</ldap:attribute> 
                <ldap:attribute>Title</ldap:attribute> 
                <ldap:attribute>physicalDeliveryOfficeName</ldap:attribute> 
                <ldap:attribute>l</ldap:attribute>     
                <ldap:attribute>st</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>postalCode</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>streetAddress</ldap:attribute>                     
        </ldap:attributes>          
    </ldap:search>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving a `List` of [`org.mule.module.ldap.api.LDAPEntry`](https://mulesoft.github.io/ldap-connector/java/org/mule/module/ldap/api/LDAPEntry.html) which is exactly what is expected [per the user guide](https://mulesoft.github.io/ldap-connector/mule/ldap-config.html#search):

> `<ldap:search>`
>
> Performs a LDAP search returning a list with all the resulting LDAP entries.

You can then process this list with a MEL expression in a transformer or component, or split it with a `collection-splitter` or iterate it with a `for-each` scope.

Comment: So is it possible to use the DataMapper with the LDAP connector? I'm confused as it doesn't detect what comes out of it (input) like it does on a SOAP webservice for example.

Comment: The LDAP Connector is not a DataSense enabled connector so the input won't be auto-detected, you'll have to manually do it. See http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/DataSense-enabled+Connectors for the list of connectors with DataSense.